# Using class-validators on Schema with frontend validation

Tags: validation, class-validator

I am in the process of learning form validation.

From what I have gathered, form input validation should be done on the frontend, whereas db & security validation should be done on the backend. (Is this correct?).

I don't understand the point of class-validators on backend schemas such as:

```
  @Field()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @Field()
  @IsString()
  @Length(4)
  @IsLowercase()
  password: string;
```

If best practice is to validate inputs on the frontend, am I essentially duplicating validation code using these decorators?

Answer (score 1):

Validating inputs in the frontend can give the user instant feedback on what fields might be wrong and what needs to change. Validating inputs in the backend ensures that you get valid values to work with. Frontend validation can be bypassed, backend validation not.

**Frontend validation is for the UX, Backend validation is for being sure you get valid values.**